# Customize Android Fonts

Tags: android, fonts, customization

Now, I'm developing an android application, which needs to show some special characters. I need this font "Arial Unicode MS" to show the characters correctly. And I add the following code in my main activity:

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.flipped_window);
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"ARIALUNI.TTF");
editText.setTypeface(font);
```

It does work. However, the size of this font file is too big, it's 22,731 kb.

Is there better solution for this problem? Thanks.

Comment: You could use a font editor and create the desired glyphs, either in a from-scratch font or in a copy of a freely-distributable font. As the others have noted, you have no rights to distribute that font, unless you are an employee of Microsoft (and perhaps not even then).

Answer (score 4):

Your real problem is redistributing a copyrighted font. :-)

Answer (score 2):

As Craig mentioned, you're illegally redistributing a copyrighted font.

My best guess would be to first look at all the glyphs available in Droid Sans; in my experience, it should be good enough unless you're looking to use it for formatting.

If you can't do that, create the symbols you need as PNG or GIF images and insert them inline.  (GIFs will be substantially smaller for black & white).

Answer (score 0):

buddy, you can decrease font size with [Font creator software](http://dl3.downloadsoftware.ir/Software/1394/03/High-Logic.FontCreator.Pro.9.0.0.Build.1916.rar) with elimination unused characters in font. you can decrease it to 50,60kb also :-)

password download link :  www.downloadsoftware.ir